# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar la ubicación en el mapa de varios elementos de un objeto json?

Tags: json, google-maps, foreach, fetch

tengo  un archivo json este contiene un objeto el cual cuenta con coordenadas de diferentes lugares, mi archivo json tiene la siguiente estructura

```
   [{direccion: 'MATEO BENITEZ 89 COL. centro TUXTEPEC MEXICO CP 38500', latitud: 
 '20.48871324385829', longitud: '-100.65457702572893'}, {direccion: 'JOSEFINA ENRIQUEZ 102   
  COL.  CENTRO TUXTEPEC CP 68300', latitud: '20.48871324385829', longitud: ' 
 -100.65457702572893'}]
```

¿que estructura o función debo de utilizar para que me muestre las coordenadas de diferentes los diferentes elementos que contiene  en un mapa con marcadores? Algo como la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] tengo este codigo de ejemplo pero no se muy bien donde es que se le tienen que reemplazar los valores, voy empezando a usar json y google maps.
Les agradeceria si me  pudieran explicar un poquito para entender como es que funciona.

```
  const getLocations = () => {
   fetch('https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/g373-n3yy.json')// archivo json ejemplo data.js?
.then(response => response.json())
.then(locations => {
    let locationsInfo = []
    
    locations.forEach(location => {
        let locationData = {
            position:{lat:location.punto.coordinates[1],lng:location.punto.coordinates[0]},
            name:location.nombre_sede                
        }
        locationsInfo.push(locationData)
    })
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((data)=>{
            let currentPosition = {
                lat: data.coords.latitude,
                lng: data.coords.longitude
            }
            dibujarMapa(currentPosition, locationsInfo)
             })
          }
      })
 }

     const dibujarMapa = (obj, locationsInfo) => {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    zoom: 4,
    center: obj
    })

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: obj,
    title: 'Tu ubicacion'
})
marker.setMap(map)

let markers = locationsInfo.map(place => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: place.position,
        map: map,
        title: place.name
    })
   })
  }
    window.addEventListener('load',getLocations)
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

En la documentación de Google Maps hay mucha información bastante útil sobre este asunto:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Como puedes observar, se realiza lo siguiente:

```
const myLatLng = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
  });
  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map,
    title: "Hello World!",
  });
```

Esto sería para crear un solo marcador, pero puedes meter esto:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map,
        title: "Hello World!",
      });
```

En un bucle para podre incluir todos los puntos que necesites.

En tu caso, además, tendrás que recorrer el JSON, para obtener la lat y lng de cada marker que desees poner, pero será simplemente un for sobre el objeto JSON.

Si quieres empezar de forma sencilla, prueba si quieres a hacerlo con un objeto que tu mismo construyas en JS, y posteriormente lo sustituyes por la llamada al JSON.

Comment: muchas, gracias pero como mando llamar al archivo json, por ejemplo si no esta en una URL, es decir si tengo los datos en un Json que yo eh creado?

Comment: Existen varias opciones para cargar un fichero JSON, podrías usar algo como esto: https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript una de las opciones más interesantes. O si utilizas jQuery y quieres simplificarte el trabajo, puedes usar $.getJSON: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: me podrías dar un ejemplo de la estructura junto con el for para los marcadores en el mapa? Soy nuevo en esto y aun no entiendo muy bien como es que funciona, estoy tratando de integrar los marcadores pero por mas que intento no me aparece nada.